# Can ‘junk DNA’ be tested to arrive at genealogy insights?

Tags: dna

I’m intrigued as to how much ‘[junk DNA](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-junk-dna-and-what/)’ differs between relatives and wonder which DNA testing companies offer such tests?

Comment: I have not heard the term "junk DNA". Can you please explain it?

Comment: @lkessler https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-junk-dna-and-what/

Answer (score 2):

**In the future?  Absolutely.**

My belief is there's no such thing as "junk DNA", we just don't yet know its purpose.  The article ColeValleyGirl linked to reinforces this:

> Although very catchy, the term "junk DNA" repelled mainstream
>   researchers from studying noncoding genetic material for many years.
>   After all, who would like to dig through genomic garbage? Thankfully,
>   though, there are some clochards who, at the risk of being ridiculed,
>   explore unpopular territories. And it is because of them that in the
>   early 1990s, the view of junk DNA, especially repetitive elements,
>   began to change. In fact, more and more biologists now regard
>   repetitive elements as genomic treasures. It appears that these
>   transposable elements are not useless DNA. Instead, they interact with
>   the surrounding genomic environment and increase the ability of the
>   organism to evolve by serving as hot spots for genetic recombination
>   and by providing new and important signals for regulating gene
>   expression. ([ref](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-is-junk-dna-and-what/))

**Right now?  Not quite.**

We do have whole-genome sequencing tests available, but they aren't yet linked to genetic genealogy databases and the results of them aren't codified in genealogical ways.  I expect things to be very different 10 (maybe even 5) years from now.  The tests range from reasonable to expensive but prices keep going down for tests with all the bells and whistles.

Speficicaly, you need a whole-genome test for the

> So, back to our questions: why don’t most DNA tests sequence the whole
>   genome, and what do they test for? Most of the time, when people order
>   genetic tests, it’s their exomic DNA that is being tested. There are
>   technical and practical reasons for this, not the least of which is
>   our lack of knowledge about how introns and other noncoding sequences
>   can affect human physiology and health. Because introns don’t
>   contribute to the final protein building code, they were once called
>   “junk DNA.” The “junk” category included introns and other portions of
>   the DNA that appeared to have no function. However, decades of
>   research have shown that portions of the “junk” DNA actually help
>   regulate human health in ways that we don’t yet fully understand. ([ref](https://blog.helix.com/dna-exome-definition/))

Some tests will look at the introns but there isn't much to do with that yet.  [Here is one study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5084913/) that makes use of that data.  There aren't a lot of commercial tests, but here are two I found that test at least some noncoding regions.

- [Helix's Exome+](https://blog.helix.com/dna-technologies-genotyping-vs-sequencing/)
- [CENTOGENE – CentoGenome](https://www.centogene.com/genetic-testing/whole-genome-sequencing-with-centogenome.html)